# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE ... wants to read excel rows that are empty

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a LOAD DATA INFILE with MySQL where the file is an excel spreadsheet file, but I keep getting an error indicating that the loading wants to read rows that are empty in the file...

I'm wondering how to tell the loader to ignore excel rows that are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` cannot read Excel spreadsheets. Convert the Excel spreadsheet to a CSV file and use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on the result of the conversion.

Comment: OK...thank you so much.  I opened the file with a text editor and saw all these tick marks or whatever that weren't showing up in Excel.  I got rid of those.  Then I had to make sure that there were no extra empty lines showing up in the text file, and it worked.  Awesome!